# Shopify price as user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

Hi i am using shopify for my store. Actually I do not want to fix price for my products. I want user add price in input as donation how much he want. 
Scenario:
There should be input box instead of fix price user add some value in input that will become price of Product.

Hope you understand.

For this i have search on google but not any accurate answer.

Please any help?
Thanks

Comment: ask shopify if it's possible considering they give you 24/7 support

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add this using the default functionality.

You can create a product with a price of $1 and instead of the price field, you will show the quantity field.

So when the user for example add $10 he will add the product with a quantity of 10. So $1x10 = $10 and you have your custom price.

Comment: But by doing this when user enter 1000 quantity it mean he will order 1000 number of products????

Comment: @FarrukhZaman that's the idea. Is there a problem if a user bought a product with 1000 quantity?